# Titanium iPad displays Appcelerator's splash before custom splash

Tags: iphone, ipad, titanium, ios7.1, titanium-alloy

I have a problem with a custom splash screen. This is an iphone-only app (meaning it's targeting only iphone in the tiapp.xml), running in the iPad simulator sdk 3.3.0, ios7.1 and Alloy.
The app should run in compatibility mode, the problem is that even though I have all resources inside my assets/ folder, the standard Appcelerator's splash screen briefly appears before the simulator switches to my custom one.

here's the folder structure:

[image]

And here's the sequence of images when the app is loaded:

[image]

[image]

From the last pic, We can still see the appcelerator's icon, so I'm guessing Titanium is loading my custom image on top of the standard one?
Could this be a bug? I figured if Titanium CAN find my img, then it isn't a problem on my end?

The weirdest thing is that I've looked in all folders for this default Appcelerator picture and couldn't find it. I've also tried a clean build & manually deleting the build and Resources generated folders.

Thanks for all the help, this is driving me nuts!

Comment: clean + build + remove the image is what I would have suggested but you've already done that. AFAIK, the only place the image would be served from is inside the assets folder.  Rename the assets folder "assetsold" or something, make a new one and put in only your image, does the problem persist?

Comment: check inside your iphone folder, there may be Appcelerator splash present.

Comment: @phil thanks for your time, I figured it out. the answer's below. Dragon I had already tried that, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work after manually deleting the app from the Simulator's system before running the project.
I'm not sure why, but it seems that the simulator somehow 'caches' the last img, and maybe it had this old img of my splash.